# some questions about the function run_epoch in ptb_word_lm.py of tensorflow rnn tuorial

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

tensorflow rnn ptb language model tuorial https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb

I have two question about **run_epoch** function in ptb_word_lm.py, only cpu device

```
for step in range(model.input.epoch_size):
feed_dict = {}
for i, (c, h) in enumerate(model.initial_state):
  feed_dict[c] = state[i].c
  feed_dict[h] = state[i].h

vals = session.run(fetches, feed_dict)
cost = vals["cost"]
state = vals["final_state"]
```

**Qustion1:** why do here need to creat a feed_dict to sess, I think in Class PTBmodel， it has create the initial state for lstm network

```
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(
    [cell for _ in range(config.num_layers)], state_is_tuple=True)
self._initial_state = cell.zero_state(config.batch_size, data_type())
state = self._initial_state

outputs = []
with tf.variable_scope("RNN"):
  for time_step in range(self.num_steps):
    if time_step > 0: tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
    (cell_output, state) = cell(inputs[:, time_step, :], state)
    outputs.append(cell_output)
```

**Qustion2:** why can sessrion.run(fetches, feed_dict) return values here, however, I try this in a test code, it return None

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Model parameters
W = tf.Variable([.3], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-.3], dtype=tf.float32)
# Model input and output
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
linear_model = W * x + b
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

# loss
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(linear_model - y)) # sum of the squares
# optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
# train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

# training data
x_train = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y_train = [0, -1, -2, -3]
# training loop
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

tvars = tf.trainable_variables()
grads = tf.gradients(loss, tvars)
train = optimizer.apply_gradients(
            zip(grads, tvars))
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init) # reset values to wrong
for i in range(100):
  print sess.run(train, {x: x_train, y: y_train})
```

it just print

```
None
None
None
..
..
```

thank you!

Comment: I have a similar question (Q1). If you understand it now, please answer.